# I attempt integrate another factor 2 in the definition of even perfect numbers

Tags: number-theory, perfect-numbers

I use the method display by Florian in [1] (in true both statments of this problem are due to Florian at 99%)  to compute from $\sigma(2n)-(\sigma(n)+\sigma(n))=2^p$ (where $\sigma$ is the sum of divisor function), really there are no reason to write the second summand in the left side display as this manner, compute I said  (solving a square equation)
$$2\sigma(2n)=1+4\sigma(n)+\sqrt{1+4\sigma(n)}$$
If $n$ is an even perfect number, it is easy to prove using Euler theorem that the previous holds. Well, I attempt as I said essay Florian's trick, I write $n=2^a\cdot m$, where $a\geq 0$ and $m$ is an odd number (caution, because in this part we don't assume that $n$ is perfect, in fact it is the goal of the method, prove that only integers that safisfies the previous equation are only even perfect numbers). It is succesfull that I can prove that, after of several computations, the equation implies $\sigma(m)=2^{a+1}$ (this is in fact the first part of the method, isolated $\sigma(m)$), with the condition that $1+4\cdot\sigma(n)$ is a square (really, I should want imply from these the structure of the integer $m$ it is, $m$ is the related Mersenne prime; it is the second part of the method, derive the structure of $m$ from $\sigma(m)$). But if failed because, with a few computations with my computer, $336$ (an integer that is a power of 2 weigthed, by Mersenne primes) find the previous structure. Then I, tired, I change to display the summand in the square rooot as this manner
$$2\sigma(2n)=1+4\sigma(n)+\sqrt{1+8n}$$
and  (caution, previous relation is a conjecture, I don't derived from the method). The computer, until 10000, only finds even perfect numbers. Perhaps it is possible find a reasonable relation that satisfying only in even perfect numbers (caution I suspect that it is not well of all, because the condition “$1+4\sigma(n)$ is a square” seems have more arithmetic information that the condition “$1+8n$ is a square”).

Thus, my question (I apologize to ask in a post of this Math Stack Exchange, because the computations and solutions could go from this community)

> **Question.** Can you find a relation that integrate the factor 2 in the definition of even perfect numbers and satisfying only by even perfect numbers?

Remark. When, in the past I tried this with odd perfect numbers, my idea was use a (known) inequality between $\sigma$ and Euler's totient function, my idea was combine the equation derived (in the easy sense) for odd perfect numbers with this inequatity (see exercise 9 a) of chapter 3 from Apostol, Introduction to Analytic Theory). I belive that this second statment isn't possible to even perfect numbers. I call your attention, too to close this ocassion, about a statment [2] by George Purdy (I have not open access) that is really very very nice. I try use this formula, but I don't obtain nothing. This statment isn't related directly with to my question, but I want put this comment here, if in future seasons someone can use this formula with the problems related with perfect numbers.

References (there is open access only to [1] in site www.fq.math.ca):

[1] H-661 On Odd Perfect Numbers p. 377-378, from The Fibonacci Quarterly, Vol. 46/47 N. 4 November 2008/2009.

[2] George Purdy, An Integral Equal to $\sigma(n)$, Problems and Solutions, Problem E 1850 [1966, 82] American Mathematical Monthly Vol. 74 N. 5 MAY 1967, p. 594-595.

Comment: Why not use the definition of perfect numbers?  (i.e., $\sigma(n) = 2n$)

Comment: Additionally, if $n$ is an even perfect number, then $n$ takes the form

$$n = 2^{p-1}(2^p - 1)$$

where $2^p - 1$ is a Mersenne prime (and therefore, $p$ too is prime).

Comment: Very thanks much for your comment, feel free in future seasons to help with problems involving the sum of divisor functions, I've read some of your post, thanks @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris

Comment: Sorry, I read first your second comment, and not the first. I've used the definition and write $1+8n$, but I don't obtain nothing after tedious computations when I follow computations and repeat Florian' s trick. I can't prove it, the full equivalence in true. Thanks, I hope that my comment go to you when I type @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris

Comment: I was wrong in last comment since I don't use $\sigma(n)=2n$, since the equation involving the quantity $1+8n$ is a conjecture. I used, if I don't wrong, thus only a part of Euler theorem, to build the first equation. But I don't use the fact that the exponent $p$ is prime.

Comment: Juan, this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1366004) might be related (albeit indirectly)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Previous Answer**

(This is not a complete solution, but only a partial answer to Juan's question.)

Let $n$ be a positive integer such that 
$$2\sigma(2n) = 1 + 4\sigma(n) + \sqrt{1 + 4\sigma(n)}.$$

Without loss of generality, suppose that
$$n = {2^a}m$$
where $a > 0$ and $\gcd(2,m) = 1$.  We want to show that $a = p - 1$ and $m = 2^p - 1$, where $p$ and $2^p - 1$ are both primes.

Substituting, we get
$$2\sigma(2^{a+1}m) = 1 + 4\sigma({2^a}m) + \sqrt{1 + 4\sigma({2^a}m)}.$$

Simplifying, we obtain:
$$2\sigma(2^{a+1})\sigma(m) = 1 + 4\sigma(2^a)\sigma(m) + \sqrt{1 + 4\sigma(2^a)\sigma(m)}$$
$$2\left(2^{a+2} - 1\right)\sigma(m) = 1 + 4\left(2^{a+1} - 1\right)\sigma(m) + \sqrt{1 + 4\sigma(2^a)\sigma(m)}$$
$$8\cdot{2^a}\sigma(m) - 2\sigma(m) = 1 + 8\cdot{2^a}\sigma(m) - 4\sigma(m) + \sqrt{1 + 4\sigma(2^a)\sigma(m)}$$
$$2\sigma(m) - 1 = \sqrt{1 + 4\sigma(2^a)\sigma(m)}$$

Squaring both sides of the last equation:
$$\left(2\sigma(m) - 1\right)^2 = 1 + 4\sigma(2^a)\sigma(m)$$
$$4{\sigma(m)}^2 - 4\sigma(m) + 1 = 1 + 4\sigma(2^a)\sigma(m)$$
$$4{\sigma(m)}^2 - 4\sigma(m) = 4\sigma(2^a)\sigma(m)$$

Now, since $\sigma(m) \geq 1$, we get
$$\sigma(m) - 1 = \sigma(2^a)$$
$$\sigma(m) = 1 + \left(2^{a + 1} - 1\right)$$
$$\sigma(m) = 2^{a+1}$$

**Added January 1, 2016**

Suppose $\omega(m) \geq 2$, where $\omega(x)$ is the number of *distinct* prime factors of $x$.  Then
$$\omega(\sigma(m)) \geq 2$$
which contradicts
$$\omega(2^{a+1}) = 1.$$

Therefore, $\omega(m) = 1$.  So either $m = q^r$ or $m = s$ for some primes $q$ and $s$.

Suppose that $m = q^r$.  Then
$$2^{a+1} = \sigma(m) = \frac{q^{r+1} - 1}{q - 1} = 1 + q + \ldots + q^r.$$
Consequently,
$$q\sigma(q^{r-1}) \equiv 0 \pmod{2^{a+1} - 1}.$$
Our required conclusions would follow if $r = 1$.  So assume to the contrary that $r > 1$.

Can you take it from here, Juan?  ^_^

**Further Edit - January 1, 2016**

From the second part of Juan's original question:

Let $n$ be a positive integer such that 
$$2\sigma(2n) = 1 + 4\sigma(n) + \sqrt{1 + 8n}.$$

Without loss of generality, suppose that
$$n = {2^b}l$$
where $b > 0$ and $\gcd(2,l) = 1$.  We want to show that $b = t - 1$ and $l = 2^t - 1$, where $t$ and $2^t - 1$ are both primes.

Substituting:
$$8\cdot{2^b}\sigma(l) - 2\sigma(l) = 1 + 8\cdot{2^b}\sigma(l) - 4\sigma(l) + \sqrt{1 + 2^{b+3}l}$$

Simplifying, we obtain:
$$\left(2\sigma(l) - 1\right)^2 = 1 + 2^{b+3}l$$

Consequently, we have
$${\sigma(l)}^2 - \sigma(l) = 2^{b+1}l.$$

If $l = 2^t - 1$ is a prime, then $\sigma(l) = 2^t$, so that
$$2^{2t} - 2^t = 2^{b+1}(2^t - 1)$$
which implies that
$$b + 1 = t.$$

It remains to show that prime $l = 2^t - 1$ is the only solution to
$${\sigma(l)}^2 - \sigma(l) = 2^{b+1}l.$$

Comment: Very thanks much for your answer, and your effort in it, and a Happy New Year @ArnieDris

Comment: You're welcome Juan!  =)

Answer (score 0):

Now, I am trying made some statement/answer myself question concerning the following *equations*, the first *equation* $(A)$:

$$2\phi(n)\sigma(2n)+(1-n)\sigma(n)=\phi(n)(1-4n)+\phi(n)(1+4\sigma(n)),$$

and the second, this $(B)$:

$$2\phi(n)\sigma(2n)=2\phi(n)+\sigma(n)\cdot(2\phi(n)+n-1),$$

where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function ($(B)$ follows from $(A)$ when we use $\sigma(n)=2n$); I obtain this $(A)$ by elimination of the quantity $\sqrt{1+8n}$, by multiplication of $\frac{-3-\sqrt{1+8n}}{-3-\sqrt{1+8n}}$ in one of the identities that we've computed in two of my posts about even perfect numbers $n=2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$.

> **Computational facts.** Thus I share with this community this information, only in the way to claim that if $n$ is an even perfect number with its Euler's form, then $n$ satisfies previous $equation$, both equations. And when I run a program written in Pascal **until $10^4$ we only find even perfect numbers of one of such $(A)$, or when you run your program only for *equation* $(B)$.** When I've tried use **Florian's trick** (see the reference [1] of myself question) the computations are very tedious and I don't find nothing useful to claim. Feel free to say something about this or this other implication, and critic, of course because I don't say that we could be use neccesarly Euler's totient function $\phi(n)$ in the answer of this question. Feel free to share previous statements and questions with your colleagues.

Thus, the question remains still without a full answer in the way to obtain

> **Goal.** The answer of my question should provide us a characterisation of even perfect numbers in the way of an *equation* that integrate another factor $2$ inside the term $\sigma(2n)$ (this was my genuine idea, copy the characterisation given in [1] for odd perfect number in an attempt to study similarities). **We should to prove that the solutions of this equation are even perfect numbers and if and only if terms of this sequence of integers.** I excuse my question/answer since I believe that is an exercise that could answer an user of this site. Thanks in advance to this community.

**References of my previous post:**

[2] Mathematics Stack Exchange, The question of this post *I attempt integrate another factor...*

[3] Mathematics Stack Exchange, [If $n$ satisfies $\left(-3+\sqrt{1+8n}\right)\sigma(n)=4\left(-1+\sqrt{1+8n}\right)\phi(n)$ then is an even perfect number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1517179/if-n-satisfies-left-3-sqrt18n-right-sigman-4-left-1-sqrt18n-rig)