# When does :$\sigma(\sigma(2n))=\sigma(\sigma(n))$ and $\sigma(n)$ is sum divisors of the positive integer $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Is there someone who can show me When does: $$\sigma(\sigma(2n))=\sigma(\sigma(n))$$ where : $\sigma(n)$ denotes the sum of divisors of the positive integer $n$ ?

Note (1) : I came across this problem when I read some papers  about

"Iterating of the sum divisors of sigma function ".

Note(2) :${\sigma}^{0}(n)=n$ and ${\sigma}^{m}(n)=\sigma({\sigma}^{m-1}(n))$ and $m \geq 1$

Thank you for any help!

Comment: do you mean $\sigma_0$ or $\sigma_1$?

Comment: I added  some necessary conditions about sigma function to define well the above equation!!!

Comment: so the question for m=2 and it is \sigma_(2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a complete solution, but only a partial answer to the question.

Without loss of generality, let $n = {2^k}m$ where $k \geq 0$ and $\gcd(2,m)=1$.

Then we have:
$$\sigma(2n) = \sigma(2^{k+1})\sigma(m) = (2^{k+2} - 1)\sigma(m)$$
$$\sigma(\sigma(2n)) = \sigma((2^{k+2} - 1)\sigma(m))$$

$$\sigma(n) = \sigma(2^k)\sigma(m) = (2^{k+1} - 1)\sigma(m)$$
$$\sigma(\sigma(n)) = \sigma((2^{k+1} - 1)\sigma(m)).$$

Therefore, the equality
$$\sigma(\sigma(2n)) = \sigma(\sigma(n))$$
holds when there exist $k \geq 0$ and an odd $m$ such that
$$\sigma((2^{k+2} - 1)\sigma(m)) = \sigma((2^{k+1} - 1)\sigma(m)).$$

Lastly, using the inequalities
$$a\sigma(b) \leq \sigma(ab) \leq \sigma(a)\sigma(b)$$
we get
$$(2^{k+2} - 1)\sigma(\sigma(m)) \leq \sigma((2^{k+2} - 1)\sigma(m)) = \sigma((2^{k+1} - 1)\sigma(m)) \leq \sigma(\sigma(2^k))\sigma(\sigma(m)).$$

Hence,
$$2^{k+2} - 1 \leq \sigma(\sigma(2^k)).$$
We are therefore sure that
$$\sigma(2^k) = 2^{k+1} - 1$$
is *not* a **(Mersenne) prime**.

Additionally, we have the lower bound
$$3 < 4 - \frac{1}{2^k} \leq \frac{\sigma(\sigma(2^k))}{2^k},$$
so that $2^k$ is not an **(even) superperfect number**.  This agrees with our earlier finding that $2^{k+1} - 1$ is *not prime*.

Answer (score -1):

$\sigma(2n)=3\times\sigma(n)$

if $m=\sigma(n)$
we should find $\sigma(3 m)=\sigma(m)$

$\sigma(3m)=4\times\sigma(m)$

then  $4\sigma(m)=\sigma(m)$

contradiction so there is no solution.

Comment: yes, thanks and i think it's has no solutions

Comment: but your answer is not a proof , i think it showed by computational evidence that has no solution

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Yes it do.

Comment: The equations are only valid under some assumptions of relative primality. For example, $\sigma(2n)=3\times\sigma(n)$ if and only if $n$ is odd.