# On the binomial series $(1+\frac{1}{8n})^{1/2}$, where $n$ is an even perfect number

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, binomial-theorem, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Since $\sqrt{1+8n}=\sqrt{8n}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{8n}}$, and $\frac{1}{8n}<1$ when $n>1$ is an integer, then we can express the real number $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{8n}}$ by its binomial series. This series starts as 
$$1+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{8n}+\frac{\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-1\right)}{2!}\left(\frac{1}{8n}\right)^2+
\frac{\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}-2\right)}{3!}\left(\frac{1}{8n}\right)^3+\cdots$$

My attempt was thus assuming that $n>1$ is (an even perfect number, it is omitted if you don't read the appendix) a fixed positive integer compute the kth term: the factor $\frac{1}{k!}\left(\frac{1}{8n}\right)^k$ is easiy compute as $\frac{1}{k!2^{3k}n^k}$, and if $k=j+1$, a product $\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}-2\right)\cdots\left(\frac{1}{2}-j\right)$ is computed as, since there are $j+1$ factors, $\frac{(-1)^j}{2^{j+1}}\cdot1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots(2j-1)$.

My question is

> **Question.** Compute in a closed form the binomial series $(1+\frac{1}{8n})^{1/2}$, where $n>1$ is a fixed integer (thus you show the general term of the expansion in a closed form). Thanks in advance.

**Appendix (Optional, I show the context of previous):** I've written a post in this Mathematics Stack Exchange that states

> **Fact 1.** If $n$ is an even perfect number then satisfies $$2\sigma(2n)-1-4n=\sqrt{1+8n},$$
>   where $\sigma(m)$ is the sum of divisors function.

Previous statement is easy to prove using Euler's theorem for even perfect numbers, see [1] for general definitions and statements or this site. Since each even perfect number is a triangle number $n=\frac{q+1}{2}\cdot q=2^{p-1}\cdot(2^p-1)$, where $q=2^p-1$ is the Mersenne's prime corresponding to $n$, it is easy to prove

> **Fact 2.** If $n=\frac{q+1}{2}\cdot q$ is an even perfect number (thus $q=2^p-1$ is its asssociated Mersenne's prime) then
>   $$2q+1=\sqrt{1+8n}$$
>   (is a positive integer).

My **goal** is put more thougths on  the equation
$$2q+1=2\sqrt{q(q+1)}\cdot\left(\text{binomial series corresponding to }\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{8n}}\right),$$
and if it is possible edit new post in this site; I don't know if this way to extract information about even perfect numbers will be useful, suggestions will be welcome. Thanks.

**References:**

[1] Perfect numbers, Generalized binomial theorem, Sum of divisors function, Mathworld or Wikipedia.

[2] [I attempt integrate another factor 2 in the definition of even perfect numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1339352/i-attempt-integrate-another-factor-2-in-the-definition-of-even-perfect-numbers)

Comment: Some people write $1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots(2j-1)$ as the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) $(2j-1)!!$ but I suspect you may prefer $\dfrac{(2j)!}{2^j j!}$

Comment: Very thanks much for your contribution @Henry,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By suggestion of an user, see comments, finally we can compute the general term as  $$\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)2^{5k+4}n^{k+1}}\binom{2k}{k}.$$
 Then for every positive integer $$(1+\frac{1}{8n})^{1/2}=1+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)2^{5k+4}n^{k+1}}\binom{2k}{k}.$$

Too we can made a change in summation index to write for a fixed (and positive) triangle number $n=\frac{t+1}{2}\cdot t$ that
$$2\sqrt{t(t+1)}\cdot\left( 1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1} \binom{2k-2}{k-1}}{k2^{4k-1}t^k(t+1)^k}\right)=2t+1,$$
thus last equation in (myself question) the post it seems that isn't special for even perfect numbers.

Finally, if $n=\frac{q+1}{2}\cdot q$ is an even perfect number, where $q$ is its corresponding Mersenne's prime, then using the equation involving the sum of divisor function, we can write
$$2\sigma(2n)-1-4n=2\sqrt{q(q+1)}\cdot\left( 1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1} \binom{2k-2}{k-1}}{k2^{4k-1}q^k(q+1)^k}\right).$$

It seems that this last, neither is useful.

Comment: I hope that there are not mistakes. Please I am waiting answers for this question or other of my posts. If you can improve my solution, I vote to close as best answer yourself answer. Any hint and suggestion too are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if it is useful for you, but you can also write the general term of the sum as $$\frac{\left(1/2\right)_{k}}{k!}\left(\frac{1}{8n}\right)^{k}
 $$ where $\left(x\right)_{k}=x\left(x+1\right)\cdots\left(x+k-1\right)$ is the Pochhammer symbol.

Comment: This post has some speculative notes,  in sense that I don't know how close it.  In any case very thanks much for your contribution @MarcoCantarini thanks in true.

Comment: @user243301 happy..........  :)